# Adding custom views to django admin interface to add more functionality

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin

So I'm trying to extend Django's admin interface. I want to add more functionality to it without overriding it completely. I have a view in my app which returns a list of users who have registered in a particular time frame (last 24 hours e.t.c.) and also a toggle button which can deactivate or activate the users at will. The thing is, I initially created it with it's own template and everything, but now I don't want to reinvent the wheel and just want to add it to django's own admin interface.

I've checked multiple solutions online, however they all involve using models, whereas I'm not trying to use any particular model. I just want to be able to pass context from my views to the template.
[image: current interface]

So I'm trying to have something like in the image above, but in the django admin interface. Like just in a div below the other fields.

Below are the views that display the data and the toggle buttons

```
@staff_member_required
def custom_admin(request):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        users_in_past_24_hours = CustomUser.objects.filter(created_at__gt=time_threshold(24))
        users_in_past_week = CustomUser.objects.filter(created_at__gt=time_threshold(168))
        users_in_past_month = CustomUser.objects.filter(created_at__gt=time_threshold(730))
        context = {"users_in_past_24_hours": users_in_past_24_hours, "users_in_past_week": users_in_past_week, "users_in_past_month": users_in_past_month}
    else:
        return redirect('unauthorized')
    return render(request, 'admin_dashboard.html', context)


@require_POST
@staff_member_required
def toggle_user_status_true(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, id=user_id)
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()

    return redirect('custom_admin')


@require_POST
@staff_member_required
def toggle_user_status_false(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, id=user_id)
    user.is_active = False
    user.save()
    
    return redirect('custom_admin')
```

Unlike the questions in the other posts, I'm not trying to override the django-admin interface. I just want to extend it and add some of my own views on its' page.

Comment: just to be sure. You want to add a new page and access it from admin landing page OR add your template in an existant page in admin ?

Comment: @EricMartin Closer to the second option. I want to be able to access the activate and deactivate buttons from django admin's landing page. I already have the views in my code, but I want to know how to call them in django admin's templates. Like how to pass the context to django admin